# Grid loads continuously

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I have created a custom module to display the grid in the admin section. The grid appears including the contents of it, but the grid shows a loading icon and the grid can't be clicked.

I tried comparing my ui_component files and my di.xml to other code that have I found, but it still doesn't fix the issue.

[image]

**Here is my di.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="GalleryGridFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
            <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="GalleryGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Vendor\ExtendedGallery\Model\ResourceModel\ExtendedBanner\Collection</argument>
        <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">GalleryGridFilterPool</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<virtualType name="Vendor\ExtendedGallery\Model\ResourceModel\ExtendedBanner\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">lof_gallery_banner</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ExtendedGallery\Model\ResourceModel\ExtendedBanner</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <!--data provider name which used in grid ui component file -->
            <item name="bagallery_banner_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\ExtendedBanner\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

**And here is my ui_component XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">bagallery_banner_listing.bagallery_banner_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">bagallery_banner_listing.bagallery_banner_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">bagallery_banner_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Banner</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/addrow</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>

<dataSource name="bagallery_banner_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">GalleryGridDataProvider</argument>
        <!-- here we pass dataprovider name which i will define in di.xml file of module in next step -->
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">bagallery_banner_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>

<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <component name="columns_controls">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">bagallery_banner_listing.bagallery_banner_listing.vendor_extendedgallery_grid_columns</item>
                </item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </component>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">bagallery_banner_listing.bagallery_banner_listing.vendor_extendedgallery_grid_columns</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">bagallery_banner_listing.bagallery_banner_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">bagallery_banner_listing.bagallery_banner_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">bagallery_banner_listing.bagallery_banner_listing.vendor_extendedgallery_grid_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filters>
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">bagallery_banner_listing.bagallery_banner_listing.vendor_extendedgallery_grid_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <!-- Mass actions which you want to add in your grid-->
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="grid/grid/massdelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete selected row record?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">bagallery_banner_listing.bagallery_banner_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">bagallery_banner_listing.bagallery_banner_listing.vendor_extendedgallery_grid_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</container>



</listing>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to the ui_components so i might be wrong.

But as far as i see you need to add an .._.._index.xml where you have something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="product_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

(this is an example from the product_listing of Magento 2)

and also the ui_component xlm itself uses `listingToolbar` to have a toolbar  instead of a container so i think

```
<container name="listing_top">
```

needs to be something like this :

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
```

for a good reference you can take a look at `magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui-component/product_listing.xml`

Comment: regarding the first suggestion that you mentioned. I already have that _._.xml file. I just forgot to include it here. Sorry for that. Regarding your second thoughts, i'll try to do it. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem , let me know if it works

Comment: I'm sorry, but changing the <container> to <listingToolbar> didn't work for me.

Comment: Well i'm afraid i'm currently learning to understand this myself so i won't be able to help you more then this. I know this solved it for me. Maybe you should take a look at the product_listing that i recommended and see what you do different

Answer (score 0):

Your ui_component file is missing with some tags or elements
There is no column tag for getting those data.
And if there any column tag like

```
<columns name="index_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="helloworld/index/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">helloworld_index_listing.helloworld_index_listing.index_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig> ....
```

in  - the name matters to make the spinner understand that the data is loaded.
Map it properly with other tag ie:

```
<item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">index_columns</item>
```

Then after clear the cache and check.